# Automating scoring of answers for a given question

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, nltk

There is a topic 'X' on which students are asked to write an English passage. Given a question, I have multiple solutions with their scorings out of 10.
For a given answer by a new candidate, one needs to read the passage and score the answer. The main focus of scoring is **vocablury** and not grammer. 
How can I automate this process? What should be the steps?
Should I like train a simple model with answers as input and their scores as output. Then for a random answer I can check what is the score given my the model trained. But I feel like this will be very basic and it's accuracy will be very less. 
I am new to machine learning. Any reading material on this..etc anything would be great help. Thanks.